# How to pass template variadic arguments by reference in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, template-meta-programming

I want to get repeated inputs, therefore I made the function to get inputs with variety of types.

```
template <typename InputType>
void get_inputs(const std::string& placeholder, InputType& input){
    std::cout << placeholder << ": ";
    std::cin >> input;
}

template <typename InputType, typename... Args>
void get_inputs(const std::string& placeholder, InputType& input, Args... args){
    get_inputs(placeholder, input);
    get_inputs(args...);
}

int main(int, char**) {
    std::string name;
    int age;
    double height;

    get_inputs(
        "name", name,
        "age", age,
        "height", height
    );

    std::cout << "INFO: " << name << ", " << age << ", " << height << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And if I enter like (the content enclosed in square bracket is user input)

**Input**

> name: [example-name] 
> age: 20 
> height: 173.5

then the result must be

**Output**

> INFO: example-name, 20, 173.5

However, the result is

**Output**

> INFO: example-name, 1, 2.12785e-314

I noticed that only the first argument was passed by reference, and the remains were passed by value. I think the problem caused by not well-defined `get_inputs` functions. How can I solve it?

Comment: `Args... args`-> `Args&... args` (or for perfect forwarding `Args&&... args`, together with `get_inputs(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`)

Comment: `Args... args` passes the arguments by value - you can use `Args&&... args` instead to perfectly forward the arguments [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/98Pz1cq7W)

Comment: Oh, thank you! I solved the problem with your idea.